# html 5 video steaming?

Tags: html

to do html 5 streaming videos, does my web server have to support it?

Comment: By streaming do you mean a dynamic video stream or a fixed video stream(which is the equivalent of just downloading a .mpeg file)

Answer (score 1):

No, your server needs no extra code, but your browser has to support it.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any special requirements on the server side, although only certain browsers (Safari, Chrome, and in some cases, Firefox) support HTML5 streaming.

For a good HTML5 video player, see http://jilion.com/sublime/video